# ASP NET Problemas con peticion GET a un JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos tengo la siguiente cuestión, tengo un método que me devuelve un simple select a mi base de datos de la tabla `AspNetUsers`, pero cuando lo llamo me tira el siguiente error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Esto es mi código, es algo muy sencillo:

```
    public JsonResult JSONUsers()
    {
        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            try
            {
                var user = db.AspNetUsers.ToList();                   
                return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

cuando paro por "breakpoint" mi código corriendo y veo la variable **user** puedo ver que tiene TODO los datos de mi tabla y cuando le doy "F5" para que me devuelva la respuesta, efectivamente mi tira un json, entonces, me doy cuenta o imagino que la respuesta se envía antes de que se realice el "query", me dí cuenta que esto solo me pasa con las tablas que Entity Framework me genera para mis usuarios, roles, etc. Alguien me podría decir como evitar esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema se da debido a que algunas propiedades de las relaciones no han terminado de cargarse a la hora de querer serializar la lista.

Una solución para este problema, es desactivar el [`LazyLoadingEnabled`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.lazyloadingenabled?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration.LazyLoadingEnabled);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=entity-framework-6.2.0), para que así, no cargue las entidades relacionadas automáticamente.

```
public JsonResult JSONUsers()
{
    using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
    {
        try
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var user = db.AspNetUsers.ToList();                   
            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Haciendo esto, sólo se cargarán los objetos de tipo `AspNetUsers`, si necesitas cargar otra entidad, podes usar [`Include`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.include?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Por ejemplo:

```
var user = db.AspNetUsers.Include(x => x.OtraEntidad).ToList();
```

En caso de querer desactivar `LazyLoadingEnabled` por defecto, podría hacerse desde el constructor del mismo `DbContext`, como menciona Rafael en [su respuesta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/296137/77052)

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, te mereces el check! ;).

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes radica en las relaciones de la **propiedades de navegación** de las tablas de autenticación de usuarios de EntityFramework.

Cuando **serializas** a **Json** los resultados devueltos, entras en un "**bucle infinito**" debido precisamente a las propiedades de navegación que ya te comente de las tablas.

En tu caso la tabla `AspNetUsers` intenta cargar las entidades relacionadas (propiedades de navegación) y estas a su vez cargan de nuevo la tabla `AspNetUsers` que vuelve otra vez a cargar las entidades realcionadas (y así sucesivamente).

A este comportamiento se le denomina **Lazy-Loading**, y está habilitado por defecto a **True** por EntityFramework.

Prueba deshabilitarlo en el Constructor de tu **`BdContext`** de la siguiente forma:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("DatabaseContext")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;    

    } ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No se retorna `NUNCA` la entidad que usas persistente como respuesta de un `webapi`, para eso existen las clases `model` o `dto` (Data Transfer Objet)

En la carpeta `Model` crea la clase

```
public class UserDto{
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    //otras propeidades
}
```

y depsues lo mapeas usando linq en la respuesta

```
public JsonResult JSONUsers()
{
    using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
    {
        var user = db.AspNetUsers.Select(x=> new UserDto()
        {
           Nombre = x.Nombre,
           //otras propiedades
        }).ToList();   

        return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

asi controlas que datos vas a enviar serializado como json en la respuesta

Comment: a quien voto negativo se ve que conoce my poco de asp.net mvc, de verdad la solucion que le van aconsejar es deshabilitar el lazy load y retornar toda la entidad? ese no es un buena practica para recomendar

Comment: Yo voté negativo. Deshabilitar Lazy-Loading **es fundamental** cuando **serializas a JSON** entidades que tienen relaciones con otras tablas de la BD. Haciendo esto, sólo traes los datos de la entidad que te interese, y si quieres los valores relacionados utilizas .Include(). Por cierto revisa tu respuesta te falta un **.** delante del ToList().

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Pero con tu logica, entonces para que se implementa el lazy load si siempre hay que deshabilitarlo? porque es algo que incluye un ORM si segun tu explicacion hay que inhabilitarlo siempre y usar el include()?. El problema no esta en habilitar o no el lazy, sino en controlar lo que se envia serializado como respuesta del webapi, si defines una entidad de model o dto no afecta el lazy

Comment: Si te fijas en mi respuesta, hablo solo de los casos en los que haya que **serializar a JSON**, y sean **entidades con relaciones a otras entidades** que puedan causar un bucle infinito en la serialización, como es el caso de la pregunta que nos ocupa.

Comment: El Lazy-Loading en otros escenarios es conveniente ponerlo a TRUE, como por ejemplo, para traer los datos de entidades relacionadas que sean **tablas maestras** (Id --> Descripción).

Comment: @RafaelAcosta lo del loop en la serializacion por el lazy load lo conozco, pero en tu respuesta estas inhabilitando desde el context de EF, con lo cual lo haces para la serializacion como para todo el resto del codigo, o se no usas lazy en ningun otro lugar, no solo en la serializacion. Pero remarco que no es este el problema, sino el aconsejar retornar una entidad persistente como respuesta del webapi